# Can I take UHT milk to iceland?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, food-and-drink, iceland

I'm planning a trip to Iceland. Since my significant other is barely addressable before she had her first coffee the question arose how we can make sure to have milk when we arrive.

The [Iceland customs website](https://www.tollur.is/english/individuals/customs/traveling-to-iceland/duty-free-imports/) lists under `Prohibited articles`:

- Uncooked milk and uncooked eggs.

On a travel site about Iceland ([only in German](https://www.islandspezialisten.de/weitere-informationen-und-dienste/importbestimmungen-island/), sorry) the regulations are stated that it is only allowed to bring `sterilized milk products` with you.

Since we often use [UHT milk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultra-high-temperature_processing), which is defined as

> Ultra-high temperature processing [...] is a food processing technology that sterilizes liquid food, chiefly milk, by heating it above 135 °C (275 °F) – the temperature required to kill spores in milk – for 1 to 2 seconds.

we were wondering if that qualifies enough to allow it to be brought to Iceland.

If it matters: We'll be arriving in Iceland by ferry.

Answer (score 3):

It is hard to be sure from that so, unless someone else has encountered the exact situation, you probably won't get a definitive answer.  Even if someone else had, they might have met a laxer or stricter customs officer.

A compromise might be to bring a small amount, enough for one day, and declare it on arrival.  If the value and weight are small then the loss of it being confiscated is small.  The little capsules in many hotels might be suitable.

Where are you staying?  If it is a hotel or hostel then you could contact them and ask whether they supply milk or whether it is easily available nearby.

I have been to Iceland but I did not need to buy milk at any point.  However, I would expect milk to be easily available in Iceland.

Comment: We plan on traveling by car for a few weeks, mostly we want to use camping sites. I don't expect problems finding milk generally, however without a fixed location UHT is preferable over fresh milk.

Comment: All kinds of dairy are easy to get on Iceland, and coffee with milk is even more easily available. I would not bring more than for the first cups of coffee and only that if you make your own coffee. Or bring powdered coffee creamer.

Comment: I have not camped in Iceland but I have camped in many other parts of Europe.  If you are camping in official sites then I would expect that a small shop would be in the site or nearby.  The selection might be poor but milk will be likely.  If you are camping in the wild then, of course, you will need to  bring all your provisions.  As you drive away from the boat, look for shopping centres.  I expect that you will find one easily and it will offer milk in many forms including UHT.

Comment: @badjohn the town where the ferry arrives (Seyðisfjörður) has a population of 600 (that's not a typo). By now I found a single grocery shop in town. I don't expect any shopping centers in the vicinity, but thanks for the suggestion ;)

Comment: Oh, and the camping sites in the highlands are usually just a plain area where you are allowed to set up your tent. Once a day someone comes by and collects the fees. I'm sure there are camping sites with shops in the more populated areas, but not everywhere.

Comment: I know that the population of the country is small but a port town with just 600 is still a surprise.  Nonetheless, even a town of 600 should have a shop that sells milk.